# Check if a linear transformation is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Check if a linear transformation $F(a+bz+cz^2) =       \begin{bmatrix}
        a+2b-2c & 2a+2b \\
        -a+b-4c & 3a+2b+2c \\
        \end{bmatrix},z\in\mathbb{C}$ is surjective.

What is the method for checking if a linear transformation is surjective?

Comment: Surjective onto *what*?

Comment: well if it's supposed to be onto some vector space $V$, than the rank of the matrix should be the same as dimension of $V$. in this case probably 2. Sou you should check if the rank of the matrix is two

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $F$ is a linear transformation defined on a 3 dimensional vector space, the range is **at most** three dimensional.